# WebBrowserTask security warning on a secure site (WInphone 7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

here is the the code i use and it works but not till have had disable a security warning telling me that the site may be insecure.

how would i invoke: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20stackoverflow&url=https://stackoverflow.com/ in a the browser from an app without having the browser flag a security warning. see last attempt bellow.

```
    var web = new WebBrowserTask();

    string str ="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20stackoverflow&url=https://stackoverflow.com/";
    web.Show();
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you wanting to disable the securing message?

Comment: i dont wnat the msg to apear at all. whats a user going to think, when they try and share a link they get a warning saying the site is insecure

Comment: Disabling security messages is a BAD idea. Perhaps you should ask how to perform the task your trying to accomplish properly instead?

Comment: ok what would the correct way of opening that url in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

using the approach you have above, i don't believe there is a way to disable the message. I suggest what loyalpenguin is saying and maybe describe what you're trying to do and if there is another way to accomplish said goal.

Comment: so i can't share a url on twitter using a browser?